# SiteUserInfoList - How to filter by email address?

Tags: powershell, user

Here is my code. The count works. However the email filter doesn't return anything (no errors either).

```
    $list = $myCTX.Web.SiteUserInfoList #.Lists["User Information List"]
    $myCTX.Load($list)
    $myCTX.ExecuteQuery()
    Write-Host $list.ItemCount
    $i = $list.Items | Where-Object {$_.Email -eq $oEmail}
    Write-Host $i -f Green
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$i = $list.Items | Where-Object {$_.Email -eq $oEmail}
```

To

```
$i = $list.Items | Where-Object {$_.EMail -eq $oEmail}
```

Notice the capitalized "M".

This should work now provided that your $oEmail contains relevant data.

Comment: changed to EMail but didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the snippet out that you pasted, Jessica, and yes, it doesnt work. First of all you need to as stated above change the letter casing, otherwise it will still be empty result. But in addition to that you need to (at least thats how I got it to work) to also load in the list items.

This works for me and will pipe out the matches on email :)

```
$list = $myCTX.Web.SiteUserInfoList #.Lists["User Information List"]
$myCTX.Load($list)
$myCTX.ExecuteQuery()
#Write-Host $list.ItemCount

$listItems = $list.GetItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery())
$myCTX.Load($listItems)
$myCTX.ExecuteQuery()

$i = $listItems | Where-Object {$_["EMail"] -eq $oEmail}
```

Besides loading the list items, also note the missing dot when getting the EMail property.